# Can't see what is inside object - Xcode debugger

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging

I can't see object variables in Xcode debugger. I haven't changed anything in Build Setting. This happend to me after Xcode update and I can only print description.

Here is a screenshot displaying what I mean:

[image: Here is a screenshot displaying what I mean]

And this is what should by displayed in object:

[image: And this is what should by displayed in object]

Comment: And you haven't overridden `[NSObject description]` or `[NSObject debugDescription]` for that class?

Comment: Yes I have.  - (NSString *)description

Comment: So that is controlling what the debugger displays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was probably bug in Xcode. With new version of Xcode it is working properly. Thank you everyone for answering

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the variable is outside the current scope. Current scope being the scope where the debugger is currently stopped.

So calling a method on the pointer to the object (which is what happens when the description is printed) will work, as you can access any memory, but the variable view might be limited to only the current scope.